# vertically center two floating elements in unknown height wrapper

Tags: html, css, css-float, centering

I am a beginner trying to do the following in css / html: 
[image]

I have two floating elements, one on the left, one on the right. I want these two elements to be vertically centered in a wrapper that has no defined height. I only found a solution for the case when the wrapper has a defined height, but my wrapper can have various heights as the text content is dynamically added.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Can you post a demo to CodePen please?

Answer (score 0):

You're best of using flex box.  On the parent element, i.e. the div, do the following:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
```

This will then ensure no matter how many items you have in the child element they are always aligned vertically.  You can then align them horizontally with align-items: center;

A visual representation is shown here:

http://codepen.io/pauljohnknight/pen/oZLJPG

Paul.